# getFromLocation using GPS

Tags: android, geocoding, locationmanager

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here. I am trying to obtain the address using reverse geocoding..`

```
if (locationGPS != null) {
                    list = geocoder.getFromLocation(locationGPS.getLatitude(),
                            locationGPS.getLongitude(), 3);

                    if (list != null) {
                        if (list.size() > 0) {
                            strZipcode = list.get(0).getPostalCode();
                            strAdminArea = list.get(0).getAdminArea();
                            strLocality = list.get(0).getLocality();
                            strAddressLine = list.get(0).getAddressLine(0);

                            Log.d(TAG, "list of address: "+ list);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Data: "+ mobileDataEnabled);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Data: "+ mobile);



                            int count = 0;
                            while ((strZipcode == null || strAdminArea == null
                                    || strLocality == null || (strAddressLine == null || strAddressLine == "USA"))
                                    && count < list.size()) {
                                strZipcode = list.get(count).getPostalCode();
                                strAdminArea = list.get(count).getAdminArea();
                                strLocality = list.get(count).getLocality();
                                strAddressLine = list.get(count)
                                        .getAddressLine(count);
                                count++;
                            }`
```

This thing works fine and gives out the right address. But sometimes it gives out null for the all of the values which i am trying to retrieve despite the fact that i have a check in place for null values.. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse Geocoder does not always return a value. It sounds weird but this is the way it is. F0r example if you hit for address 5 times, you won't be lucky enough to get response for all hits. You may get 3 instead. So workaround may be, instead of hitting geocoder one at a time, try looping your request to 2 or 3 times or more, one of the requests will work hopefully.

Comment: but i am requesting 3 different addresses in the getFromLocation

Comment: are you hitting them with a delay or at once? if delay then how much delay ?

Comment: By delay do you mean the minTime in requestLocationUpdates?

Comment: No .. by delay I mean difference between requests sent t0 GeoCoder?

Comment: i am not sending multiple request to the geocoder... The code snippet i posted above is all to it..

Comment: I meant when you use GeoCoder. Anyways, tell me do you use GeoCoder everytime you get a location from GPS? if yes then what is minTime between location updates?

Comment: the minTime is 3 secs.. The thing is this works fine on all devices i tested...except for one..and that device is showing null for all this time

Comment: Try increasing this time and you will see better results ... as i read somewhere that diffrence between ussing geocoders must be atleast 15sec. n mostly it works. But again it may not work everytime.

Comment: But then it doesn't make sense that the same device would keep showing me null whereas other devices wont.

Comment: And it shouldn't be showing null in the first place. I have checks in place to deal with it

Comment: try reebooting device and try ... sometime this works ... But I am explicitly talking about that one one device you get address sometime and sometime null.

Comment: No that device shows null all the time.. It shouldn't..If anything like the street address,zip is null it should go into the while loop..